# How to use asp.net identity pages such as Change Password - /Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword - in a native mobile app?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

We are using Identity Server 4 + ASP.NET Core Identity to provide the central identity solution to a new native mobile app written using React Native and a MVC web application. Authenticating user inside an embedded webview in the mobile app using an Auth Code Flow (with PKCE) is working fine as expected and the tokens are received from the identity server react-native-app-auth library in the mobile app so no issues with using the login functionality in the mobile app.

There is a requirement of providing Change Password functionality in the mobile app. There is already change password page available out-of-the-box as part of ASP.NET Core Identity at /Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword endpoint which can be accessed using a browser in the web application. Reusing this page inside the web application will be pretty straight forward, but it probably won't be that easy to use this functionality in the mobile app. Can we reuse this page inside the mobile app somehow? The other option is that we build the UI for change password natively in the mobile app and provide an API endpoint for this but that's more work and not sure whether this is a good practice from the security point of view. It also doesn't feel right redeveloping this functionality and not reusing it if we went with this option.

Comment: Your identity server should handle changing the password, not the app, otherwise you're blurring the responsibility of the 2. By deferring your auth to an SSO, you're removing auth from your app. What if you changed SSO, or enabled federation? How would password change in your app cope in those scenarios?

Comment: @SimonHalsey yes I agree with you so I was wondering how someone would have solved this problem of providing change password functionality in the mobile by reusing the functionality that already exist in our identity platform. Perhaps this functionality (i.e. change password) doesn't really belong to the mobile app given our architecture where the identity platform is a separate service and we might just provide this functionality in a web application as it would be easy to integrate it within a web application.